# How to restore an array with NSCoder

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch, xcode, nscoding

So far I have the following:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*) coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder: coder];
    if (self) {
        // Call a setup method
    }
    return self;
}
```

Am I supposed to put the code to load the array in here? What could should I put and where should I put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put `myArray=[coder decodeObjectForKey:@"myArray"];` inside the if block.

If you haven't set up the encoding part of the code yet, to do that you just add a method:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:myArray forKey:@"myArray"];
}
```

Comment: That would result in `myArray` being released next time the autorelease pool is drained - you need to take ownership of it.